# Form's title and/or logo.

Tags: layout

As you can see some applications have a logo or/and title at the top left side. Does it help to understand where is the user at this moment (what form user is working with)?  Are there any other ways to return user's attention after distraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top left corner is where surfers expect to find the company logo.  And with time, it has also become common usage to expect to be able to click on that logo to go to the home page.

I wouldn't use that area to give an indication on the particular form.  Instead, I suggest that you have the form name or description beneath the logo, or, if you don't have a navigation bar, to the right of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is value to using iconography to show users quickly where they are - up to a point. The up side is that international users can still use the form (eg, I don't know the French phrase for Shipping Method but a cardboard box with a question mark on it would let me know that's what I needed to decide). I think if you hint at a call to action in your icons (like the question mark in my previous example) then users will move along appropriately and not admire your pretty icons for too long.